# How to split MySQL database connection in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i wrote a login page with jsp , but all segments are mixed .
i want to split database connection to a java class .

Mysql database connection code :

```
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3232/jsp";
Connection connection = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "123456");
if (connection.isClosed()) {
    out.println("Connection Faild !");
}

PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM jsp_users WHERE user_login = '" + User + "' AND user_password = '" + Pass + "'");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
int id = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    id = rs.getInt("id");
}
```

Comment: You should reseach using prepared statements in jsp (Java).. The variables User and Pass looks to be prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: PLEASE DON"T DO THIS, the attack will be easy. 
You can add the properties file in the webserver in order to be more secure and you can create Connections pool there

Comment: Yes i know , That's not secure .
but at this step just i want to split mysql connection to More extensibility .